# react native error TypeError: network request failed fetch http

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, fetch-api

I'm trying to make a post request to my remote api to login and get some data, it works fine on expo go and on development build but it doesn't work on production build, even when is the same ip address sent through the same http protocol, I tried to add the "usesCleartextTraffic": true in my app.json since I don't have manifest on my project, but nothing works, here is my request:

```
import BASEPATH from './basepath'

export const postJSON = (url, data={}) => {
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
        fetch(BASEPATH() + url, {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'access-method': 'api-json',
            },
            // credentials: 'same-origin',
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response){
                if (response.hasOwnProperty('json')){
                    response.json().then(function (res) {
                        resolve(res);
                    }).catch(function (res) {
                        reject(res);
                    });
                }else{
                    response.text().then(function (res) {
                        resolve(res);
                    }).catch(function (res) {
                        reject(res);
                    });
                }
            }else{
                reject(res);
            }
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log({err})
            resolve(err);
        });
    });
}
```